# iOS7 - In app purchases issue

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase

I have uploaded an application to AppStore to a customer. Everything works fine except In App Purchases. They are able to buy a product, but the delegate methods doesn't seem to be fired for complete transaction. Although, If they pressed the "restore" button (which I made) they get back what they bought, so my issue is that I need to be able to confirm their product without having to restore it.

My header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface StartViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *product;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request;

@end
```

My main file (relevant parts):

```
       - (void)buyPro1{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        self.productID = PRODUCT_ID_PRO1; // NSString
        self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                      initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                      [NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        self.request.delegate = self;
        [self.request start];

        NSLog(@"starting buy!!");
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [a show];
    }
}  

        - (void)buyPro2{
            if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
                self.productID = PRODUCT_ID_PRO2; // NSString


    self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                            initWithProductIdentifiers:
                            [NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
            self.request.delegate = self;
            [self.request start];

            NSLog(@"starting buy!!");
        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [a show];
        }
    }

#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    NSLog(@"starting buy 2!!");

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        self.product = products[0];

        NSLog(@"pro: %@", self.product.localizedTitle);
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"pro: not found");
    }

}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if([self.productID isEqualToString:PRODUCT_ID_PRO1]){
                    [[SessionManager sharedSession] setAppLimitVersion:PRO_ONE];
                    UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Du har nu 3 veckors schemat" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                    [a show];
                }
                else if([self.productID isEqualToString:PRODUCT_ID_PRO2]){
                    [[SessionManager sharedSession] setAppLimitVersion:PRO_TWO];
                    UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Du har nu 6 veckors schemat" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                    [a show];
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:{
                UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Betalningen misslyckades" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                [a show];

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [a show];
}
```

I would put up a bounty for this but I'll have to wait 2 days for that. Any one that can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I highly recommend follwing this great tutorial and then see where you went wrong.(http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial). But it basically creates a singleton to manage all of the IAP's. Also make sure you properly created the IAP in iTunesConnect.

Comment: I've used [CargoBay](https://github.com/mattt/CargoBay) in the past, which does a nice job of wrapping some of the key IAP functionality.